# Formatting email layout issue Outlook 2013 - Windows 7

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I have modified an email template (from Campaign Monitor) that is responsive and works on most email browsers.

But, the email header is running into formatting issues on Outlook 2013, Windows 7.

I have messed with the formatting inline and using CSS to attempt to find a solution.

**Correct Email**

[image]

**Outlook 2013, Windows 7**

[image]

I have created a JSFiddle to review the HTML code: https://jsfiddle.net/jeremyccrane/wz4Ly555/

```
    <!--[if mso]>
<body class="mso">
  <![endif]-->
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
  <body class="half-padding" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;min-width: 100%;background-color: #E7E7E7;">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <center class="wrapper" style="display: table;table-layout: fixed;width: 100%;min-width: 620px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #E7E7E7;">
      <table class="header centered" style="border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;Margin-left: auto;Margin-right: auto; width: 600px;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0;vertical-align: top;">
              <table class="one-col" style="border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;Margin-left: auto;Margin-right: auto;width: 600px;background-color: #ffffff;table-layout: fixed;" emb-background-style>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="column" style="padding: 0;vertical-align: top;">
                      <table class="contents" style="border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;table-layout: fixed;width: 100%; background:#EE3524;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="remove-padding" style="padding: 0;vertical-align: top;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;word-break: break-word;word-wrap: break-word;">
                              <div class="image" style="font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;Margin-bottom: 0;Margin-top: 0;font-family: sans-serif;color: #000;" align="center">
                                <img style="border: 0;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;display: block;" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/bif26pxsl39mv5u/HEADER.png?raw=1" class="" width="600px"/>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Outlook2013 litmus test]

I tested the html from the jsfiddle in Litmus, and seems to be oke.

Can you more explain how to get the two red area's

Comment: Thanks @joris-ros. In Litmus it appears to render correctly but when the email is received on the client inbox it does not render correctly.

Comment: Do you know more about the specific configuration? Litmus makes the screenshot on windows 7, the only thing that comes in my mind is that the render engine is depending on a old IE version or something like that.

Comment: I believe the rendering engine being utilized for Exchange 2007/2010/2013 is microsoft word HTML viewer built into Exchange. Not sure how Litmus renders that using their software.